# Dynamic DataTable to chart one row across the row

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a datatable that is drawing data from a database dynamically, and correctly displaying the data on a piechart. However, after having searched abundantly, I am still having problems doing the following, please keep in mind I am new to javascript and it could be something minor that I am missing.

1. The piechart is working fine, but I would like the chart to display data only from the first row, and not all rows as it is currently doing. I have tried:

   - "startRow: 2, endRow: 3" - This works with other charts but with the code I have below, it doesn't work no matter where I put it.
   - I have also tried ""pageLength": 1," which applies to the datatable but the chart still displays all rows.
2. On a separate chart from the same datatable, I would like to chart data across the row and not down the column. I have tried "switchRowsAndColumns: true".

Again this solution works with other tables but not with the code I'm using, which draws the chart according to the info in the table, which will be generated through the search function or filters. If I can have both charts displayed as a series each rendered to a separate container that would be great.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sm4n2vwg/41/) (pls ignore slice labels)

Attached is the code (I am using a static table but my table is dynamic):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

                // Initialize  table


var c20BhvDt = $("#c20Bhv").DataTable({
                });

        var kc20BhvPieChart = Highcharts.chart("container", {

            chart: {
                type: "pie",
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
            },

            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
    colors: ['#64c987', '#d16035', '#e58b38', '#fafa6e', '#b53535', '#099FFF'],

                    
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    slicedOffset: 30,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    innerSize: '10%',
                    borderWidth: 3,
                    borderColor: '#2d3035',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#EF8C99',
                        connectorColor: '#EF8C99'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{                
                      data:  chartData(c20BhvDt, 7),
            name: 'Students',
                        dataLabels: {
                        style: {
                            fontSize: 16,
                            textOutline: '#2d3035'
                        },
                        formatter: function() {
                            const point = this.point;
                            return '<span style="color: ' + point.color + '">' +
                                point.name + ' - ' + point.y + ' Students</span>';
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],            
        });

        c20BhvDt.on("draw", function() {
            kc20BhvPieChart.series[0].setData(chartData(c20BhvDt));
        });
    });

function chartData(c20BhvDt, column = 7) {
    var counts = {};

    c20BhvDt
        .column(column, {
            search: "applied"
        })
        .data()
        .each(function(val) {
            if (counts[val]) {
                counts[val] += 1;
            } else {
                counts[val] = 1;
            }
        });

    return $.map(counts, function(val, key) {
        return {
            name: key,
            y: val,
        };
    });
};
```

```css
#container {
    height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

#c20Bhv {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

#c20Bhv caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}

#c20Bhv th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

#c20Bhv td,
#c20Bhv th,
#c20Bhv caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

#c20Bhv thead tr,
#c20Bhv tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

#c20Bhv tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/dt-1.12.1/sb-1.3.3/sp-2.0.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/searchpanes/js/dataTables.searchPanes.js?13"></script>
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/select/js/dataTables.select.js?_=9a6592f8d74f8f520ff7b22342fa1183"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<figure class="highcharts-figure">
        <div id="container">
        </div>
        <table id="c20Bhv" class="Stabel" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
         <tr class="bg-secondary text-light text-large">
         <td colspan="8" class="text-center">Student Info</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <th class="text-center">ID</th>
         <th class="text-center">EX</th>
         <th class="text-center">NP</th>
         <th class="text-center">Sl</th>
         <th class="text-center">LT</th>
         <th class="text-center">WR</th>
         <th class="text-center">BTH</th>
         <th class="text-center">SCR</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td class="text-center">21204</td>
        <td class="text-center">4</td>
        <td class="text-center">7</td>
        <td class="text-center">3</td>
        <td class="text-center">7</td>
        <td class="text-center">2</td>
        <td class="text-center">1</td>
        <td class="text-center">87</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="text-center">21205</td>
        <td class="text-center">5</td>
        <td class="text-center">3</td>
        <td class="text-center">5</td>
        <td class="text-center">9</td>
        <td class="text-center">5</td>
        <td class="text-center">2</td>
        <td class="text-center">83</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="text-center">21206</td>
        <td class="text-center">8</td>
        <td class="text-center">3</td>
        <td class="text-center">5</td>
        <td class="text-center">6</td>
        <td class="text-center">1</td>
        <td class="text-center">6</td>
        <td class="text-center">93</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="text-center">21207</td>
        <td class="text-center">6</td>
        <td class="text-center">3</td>
        <td class="text-center">8</td>
        <td class="text-center">4</td>
        <td class="text-center">7</td>
        <td class="text-center">4</td>
        <td class="text-center">83</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="text-center">21208</td>
        <td class="text-center">3</td>
        <td class="text-center">7</td>
        <td class="text-center">6</td>
        <td class="text-center">3</td>
        <td class="text-center">2</td>
        <td class="text-center">8</td>
        <td class="text-center">74</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="text-center">21209</td>
        <td class="text-center">3</td>
        <td class="text-center">4</td>
        <td class="text-center">3</td>
        <td class="text-center">8</td>
        <td class="text-center">9</td>
        <td class="text-center">6</td>
        <td class="text-center">69</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </figure>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: When I use startRow, endRow, startColumn, endColumn I can manipulate with the data I want to work with. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vqLk29ej/)